# Get declared variable from different classes

Tags: java, class, variables, public

Ok, I have a method in my main class that gets a random words from a file. I have a form that I want to be able to get that random Word from the other class. I am not too skilled with public variables and lack an understanding of them. Any suggestions are welcome too. Thank you!

```
public class Project {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws IOException
{
    pickWord();
    frmPlaying.main(args);
    //To be honest I only know this shows the form and don't know why
}

public static void pickWord()
        throws IOException
{
    File words = new File("wordList.txt");
    String wordToArray = new String();
    String[] arrWord = new String[3863];   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(words);
    Random rWord = new Random();
    int i = 0;


    do
    {
        sc.nextLine();
        wordToArray = sc.next();
        arrWord[i] = wordToArray;
        i++;    
    }while(sc.hasNext());

    Arrays.toString(arrWord);
    int idx = rWord.nextInt(arrWord.length);
    String randomWord = (arrWord[idx]);
    return randomWord;

}
```

}

^^^^ Gets random word

```
/* try
    {
        Project.pickWord();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    */
```

suspected code for getting the random word

Comment: instead of throwing IOException type `return randomWord`, change the return type to String and access it with `String word = Project.pickWord()`.

Comment: Question why is your method static ? can you share the rest of the class ?

Comment: It is static because I at first thought that was how you made it public and have not changed it since.

Answer (score 0):

Give your method a return type. Learn something about it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

```
public static String pickWord()
    throws IOException{
....
String randomWord = (arrWord[idx]); /* Random Word I want this to be */
return randomWord;
}
```

Comment: Ok making it `static` would make it available in other classes. But you don't explain that at all, so this is of not much help to the OP question.

Comment: it was static, i dont change it.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to make `String randomWord` also static?

Comment: randomWord static? What? Its a local variable inside the method

Comment: OP: Random Word I want this to be accessible to the other class but don't know how

Comment: no that "random word" from file not the variable random word. ;)

Comment: Probably me, too much SO for me today. :)

Comment: could me, too :D lets wait for OP :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion? I think the problem lies with my lack of defining. I set the randomWord to equal the word at the randomly selected index. Whatever it may be I want to be able to "call" it from my Form code. You're all just to smart for me after all XD. So I would need to make the randomWord static? Also would I really need a "return" at the end seeing how it is not in a loop and will not go anywhere?

Comment: Since randomWord is a local variable, you can't make it static.

Comment: Ooh. Thanks. So in order to solve my issue I would just need to find a way to make it static or whatever I think I get what you mean now. Thanks all of you!

Comment: I would make a seperate new class and put the variables in there as class variables and initialize them in the constructor also declare the methods there. You should not put those in the main class.